# buttons and label does not resize when going to full screen in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a GUI that has three buttons and a label. But when I go full screen the buttons and the label does not go to full screen even if i am using show full screen. Here is my code.

```
class App(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1500, 617)
        self.processedImgLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.processedImgLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 1420, 520))
        self.processedImgLabel.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.processedImgLabel.setText("")
        self.processedImgLabel.setObjectName("processedImgLabel")
        self.processedImgLabel.showFullScreen()
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 1291, 25))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.startButton.setObjectName("startButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.detectButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.detectButton.setObjectName("detectButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.detectButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "App"))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Start"))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Stop"))
        self.detectButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Exit"))
```

Here is what is happening:
Before full screen.
[image]

After full screen
[image]

Comment: You need to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), read the documentation about [using them on Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already used a QHBoxLayout you understand the advantages, the same thing you have to do in the vertical part, for this you have several options:

- QGridLayout:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ui version="4.0">
   <class>Dialog</class>
   <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>400</width>
      <height>300</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="windowTitle">
     <string>Dialog</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Start</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopButton_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Pause</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Exit</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="processedImgLabel">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <resources/>
   <connections/>
  </ui>
  ```
- QVBoxLayout

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ui version="4.0">
   <class>Dialog</class>
   <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>400</width>
      <height>300</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="windowTitle">
     <string>Dialog</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0,1">
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Start</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Pause</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Exit</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="processedImgLabel">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <resources/>
   <connections/>
  </ui>
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using slightly different version than yours. But the idea helped a lot.